# Why can’t I answer my first question

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

[Generic term for sunrise and sunset](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144639/generic-term-for-sunrise-and-sunset)

Comment: Although the nominated duplicate mentions having 101 rep points rather than just 1, the answer is relevant. You have to earn reputation on other questions before being able to answer a protected question.

Answer (score -3):

You can now. I’ve unprotected it.